# Problem uploading images in cpanel in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to upload images on a shared hosting but am unable to upload. On my machine it works well but when I host i cant figure how to change the paths.All the other pages are working fine except uploading images.

```
on my controller
foreach ($images as $image){
         $move=$image->move(public_path().'/images2/',time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName()); 
         if($move){
         $imagedata=Images::create([
        'title'=>time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName(),
        'filename'=>time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName()
        ]);
```

Displaying the previous images is okay with this code on the view side

```
 @foreach($product_images as $image)
    <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
     <div> <img class="d-block w-100 newim" src="/images2/{{$image->filename}}"/></div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is here with the wrong "," :

```
$move=$image->move(public_path().'/images2/',time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName());
```

change it to:

```
$move=$image->move(public_path().'/images2/'.time().'_'.$image->getClientOriginalName());
```

and make sure your folders are same name as you wrote in your code because host is sensitive to uppercase or lowercase

Comment: thanks the problem is that when i upload it creates a folder public/images but i had transfered the images folder in public_html in cpanel

Answer (score 0):

I added this to index php though not sure whether it is secure but it works

```
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
  return realpath(__DIR__.'/../public_html/');
});
```